# How to change content between [block] of puppet file with sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

This jail.conf file. I want to change [maxretry = 6] to maxretry = 5 with sed for puppet file.

```
[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6

[dropbear]

enabled  = false
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/dropbear
maxretry = 6
```

How can I do?

My puppet command.
exec { "fail2banadd":
  command => '/bin/sed  -i "/[ssh]/,/[dropbear]/ s/maxretry = 6/maxretry = 5/" /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf',
}

I got this error.

=> default: err: /Stage[main]//Exec[fail2banadd]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: /bin/sed
-i "/[ssh]/,/[dropbear]/ s/maxretry = 6/maxretry = 5/" /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf returned 2 inste
d of one of [0] at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/manifests/init.pp:76

Comment: To remove all ambiguity, would you show your desired output?

Comment: I got this error when i run puppet file.
==> default: err: /Stage[main]//Exec[fail2banadd]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: /bin/sed
 -i "/\[ssh\]/,/\[dropbear\]/ s/maxretry = 6/maxretry = 5/" /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf returned 2 inste
ad of one of [0] at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/manifests/init.pp:76

Comment: This my code.
exec { "fail2banadd":   
  command => '/bin/sed  -i "/\[ssh\]/,/\[dropbear\]/ s/maxretry = 6/maxretry = 5/" /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf',
}

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this with `awk`

```
awk '/^maxretry/ {$3=5} 1' jail.conf > tmp && mv tmp jail.conf
```

Updated:

```
awk '/\[ssh\]/,/\[dropbear\]/ {if (/^maxretry/) next} /^maxretry/ {$3=5} 1' jail.conf
[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log

[dropbear]

enabled  = false
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/dropbear
maxretry = 5
```

Comment: Sorry. My question not clear. I need to delete maxretry between [ssh] and [dropbear] only.Can you hekp me?

Comment: @PhanatBettaFarm See my updated.  First `maxretry` deleted, second changed to `5`. PS Update your post with this info.

Answer (score 0):

#### Version 1

This `sed` solution changes only the maxretry value between `[ssh]` and `[dropbear]`:

```
$ sed  -i"" '/\[ssh\]/,/\[dropbear\]/ s/maxretry = 6/maxretry = 5/' jail.conf
```

The output looks like:

```
[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 5

[dropbear]

enabled  = false
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/dropbear
maxretry = 6
```

#### Version 2

This variation deletes the `maxretry` entry between `[ssh]` and `[dropbear]` and changes all other `maxretry = 6` entries to `maxretry = 5`:

```
sed  -i"" 's/maxretry = 6/maxretry = 5/; /\[ssh\]/,/\[dropbear\]/ {/maxretry/d}' jail.conf
```

Comment: See comment in my post. `maxretry` in `ssh` should be deleted too.